# How to rewrite this jQuery code by using Mootools?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have a jQuery code, **but need it working by using Mootools:**

```
if ( $("span.mailme").length ) {
  var at = / AT /;
  var dot = / DOT /g;

  $('span.mailme').each(function () {
    var addr = $(this).text().replace(at, '@').replace(dot, '.');
    $(this).after('<a href="mailto:' + addr + '">' + addr + '</a>');
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

Is there anyone, who know as good Mootools as jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mailme = $$('.mailme'), at = / AT /, dot = / DOT /g;

mailme.each(function(el){
    var addr = el.get('text').replace(at, '@').replace(dot, '.');

    new Element('a', {
        href: 'mailto:'+ addr,
        html: addr
    }).inject(el, 'after');

    el.destroy();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/MJujB

Comment: Thank you very much, Oskar! Works great for me.
You are cool and precise as usual.

Comment: Mentioned your Mootools conversion on one of my blog posts. Great job!